# expo jest test won't run

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

```
Hello everyone.

I'm making unit tests on react-native to test my web 
pages/screens on my windows computer using a local host 
connection, node project manager, and command prompt. 

My testing library is the react testing library and I already 
have installed it on my directory by following the instructions 
in the link:  
https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro

However, when I ran the command npm run test on command 
prompt, it shows the expo help command options on command prompt 
instead of running jest and showing the results of my unit test

Below are my files for reference

**Here's my unit test Header.test.js:**
```

It's for testing if title on the header of the Projects page will
equal a title that I want on my page and then rerender that title

````
```react-native
import {render} from "@testing-library/react";
import Header from "../components/header/index";

test("test theme button toggle", () => {
  const title = "Projects";

  const { container, rerender } = render(
    <Header title={title} />
  );

  expect(container.innerText).toEqual(title);

  const newTitle = "Hello";

  rerender(
    <Header title={newTitle} />
  );

  expect(container.innerText).toEqual(newTitle);
});
```

**Here's the package.json script**
 
This is where my scripts for testing with jest are at. Let me 
know if there's a problem is here. I just followed the 
instructions for this on this link: 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-expo


```react-native
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.14.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-font": "^9.1.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.2.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react- 
    native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-native": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@react-test-renderer": "~16.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```


**Now here's what happens when I run it on command prompt.**
````

I'm using the command npm run test, which should run jest-expo since I set that as the pre-set in the package.json file above.

````
```Command Prompt
C:\Users\adity\For Real\client>npm run test

> @ test C:\Users\adity\For Real\client
> expo


  Usage: expo [command] [options]

  Options:

    -V, --version                     output the version number

    --non-interactive                 Fail, if an interactive 
                                      prompt would be required to 
                                      continue.

    -h, --help                        output usage information

  Commands:

    init [name]                       Create a new Expo project
    start [path]                      Start a local dev server 
                                      for the app

    start:web [path]                  Start a Webpack dev server 
                                      for the web app

    publish [path]                    Deploy a project to Expo 
                                      hosting

    export [path]                     Export the static files of 
                                      the app for hosting it on a 
                                      web server

    install [packages...]             Install a unimodule or 
                                      other package to a project

    run:android [path]                Run the Android app binary 
                                      locally

    run:ios [path]                    Run the iOS app binary 
                                      locally

    send [path]                       Share the project's URL to 
                                      an email address

    login                             Login to an Expo account
    logout                            Logout of an Expo account
    register                          Sign up for a new Expo 
                                      account

    whoami                            Return the currently 
                                      authenticated account

    client:install:ios                Install Expo Go for iOS on 
                                      the simulator

    client:install:android            Install Expo Go for Android on a connected device or emulator

    config [path]                     Show the project config
    diagnostics [path]                Log environment info to the 
                                      console

    doctor [path]                     Diagnose issues with the 
                                      project

    upgrade [sdk-version]             Upgrade the project 
                                      packages and config for the 
                                      given SDK version

    publish:set [path]                Specify the channel to 
                                      serve a published release

    publish:rollback [path]           Undo an update to a channel
    publish:history [path]            Log the project's releases
    publish:details [path]            Log details of a published 
                                      release

    build:ios [path]                  Build and sign a standalone 
                                      IPA for the Apple App Store

    build:android [path]              Build and sign a standalone 
                                      APK or App Bundle for the 
                                      Google Play Store

    build:web [path]                  Build the web app for 
                                      production

    build:status [path]               Get the status of the 
                                      latest build for the 
                                      project

    credentials:manager [path]        Manage your credentials

    fetch:ios:certs [path]            Download the project's iOS 
                                      standalone app signing 
                                      credentials

    fetch:android:keystore [path]     Download the project's 
                                      Android keystore

    fetch:android:hashes [path]       Compute and log the 
                                      project's Android key 
                                      hashes

    fetch:android:upload-cert [path]  Download the project's 
                                      Android keystore

    push:android:upload [path]        Upload an FCM key for 
                                      Android push notifications

    push:android:show [path]          Log the value currently in 
                                      use for FCM notifications 
                                      for this project

    push:android:clear [path]         Delete a previously 
                                      uploaded FCM credential

    url [path]                        Log a URL for opening the 
                                      project in Expo Go

    url:ipa [path]                    Log the download URL for 
                                      the standalone iOS binary

    url:apk [path]                    Log the download URL for 
                                      the standalone Android 
                                      binary

    webhooks [path]                   List all webhooks for a 
                                      project

    webhooks:add [path]               Add a webhook to a project
    webhooks:remove [path]            Delete a webhook
    webhooks:update [path]            Update an existing webhook

    upload:android [path]             Upload an Android binary to 
                                      the Google Play Store

    upload:ios [path]                 Unsupported: Use eas submit 
                                      or Transporter app instead.

    customize:web [path]              Eject the default web files 
                                      for customization

    eject [path]                      Create native iOS and 
                                      Android project files. 
                                      Learn more:
````

https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/

````
    prebuild [path]                   Experimental: Create native 
                                      iOS and Android project 
                                      files before building 
                                      natively. Learn more:
                                      https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/

  client:ios [path]                 Experimental: build a 
                                    custom version of Expo Go for 
                                    iOS using your own Apple 
                                    credentials

  Run a command with --help for more info 
    $ expo start --help
```


Does anyone know what's going on? I tried all kinds of 
configurations for jest on the jest testing library and I still 
can't figure out how to fix this.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can tell what's going 
wrong with my code and get jest to run instead of expo.

From,
Aditya Duggirala
````

j

Comment: Could you perhaps embed your screenshots in the question itself instead of using links? The links might break with time. Keep in mind that it might be more suitable to include source code or output from tests as formatted text rathe than images.

Comment: Ok, I did the changes you asked of me @Maritim

Comment: @Maritim Will you over answer my question?